# how to make git merge using console command line to see branches in gitkraken software?

Tags: git, gitkraken

Hello I'm using **gitkraken** to analyze my git local repository
I don't see my branch in **gitkraken** using this code in my last operation with "task2" folder:

```
git init
git checkout -b task2 // create new branch
mkdir task2 // create folder
//create file main.java
git checkout master // return to master branch
git merge task2 // get changes from task2 to master
```

**p.s.** operation **Merge branch task1** in screenshot was made in gitKraken software and its work all I expected - draw me new branch

[image: GitKraken screen]

Comment: Did you commit anything on branch `task2`? From the commands you posted it seems you just created a file then switched the branch to `master`. The changes that were not committed do not belong to any branch because they are not in the repository yet but only in your working copy.

Answer (score 0):

After **mkdir task2 // create folder**, you need to commit your changes in the task2 branch.

`git commit -am "commit message"`

then check out to master and merge task2 to master branch.